# php echo of file generating syntax and mime type errors

Tags: javascript, php, mime-types

inside php

```
echo file_get_contents("modules/search/view/templates/form.html");
```

form.html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Upload PDF</title>
<base href="Education" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modules/search/view/templates/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modules/search/view/templates/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

.htaccess file inside Education folder (URL: `http://localhost/Education/search/form`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

not sure how can we fix the syntax and mime errors, please advise.

[image]

Comment: Where's your DOCTYPE and closing `</html>` tag?

Comment: missed while pasting, it's in the code, edited post as well. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Try changing this: `<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />`

Comment: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` is not valid.

Comment: `charset` is relatively new in HTML5.

Comment: @developerwjk -  why is not valid? Is completely legal in HTML5. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)

Comment: It's valid. Is the file that you are echoing, or the page you are echoing it from not saved as anything other than UTF-8 charset in your editor?

Comment: Lol. Can't believe they added something so asinine. The old way you set both mimetype and charset at once. Hence your problem, you're only setting one due to the new bug, er, I mean feature of HTML5.

Comment: my editor is saving as utf-8, still getting same errors (tried above meta tags also)

Comment: it's an html5 document so

Comment: Did you check every one of those JavaScript links in you console and see if they were saved correctly? Make sure their `Language` is set correctly in your editor. They're being read as HTML.

Comment: Close <meta> and <link> tags, adding a slash at the end of the tag: <link ... />

Comment: That's only part of a Document. In `inside.php` you need to `echo "<body>$stuffHere</body></html>";`.

Comment: one thing for sure, if I view the page standalone no problem, but when I go through localhost and display via PHP, I get these errors

Comment: Further safari is only displaying javascript errors, chrome displaying both.

Comment: also I'm using .htaccess file on the server